# How to get old environment data into new environment?

Tags: apex, managed-package

Here is my requirement.

I Installed package old org to new Org, i want to get old environment data into New                         Environment. is It Possible ?...

Comment: Any one help me regarding above issue?

Comment: You'll have to do a data export/import to get the data across using either the data loader, 3rd party tool or UI tools inside SFDC. You'll have to check your schema and see which objects have data records added (use data management tools especially data usage metric to see where the data is) or the workbench app - https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php

Comment: Is there any possibility to get old environment records into new environment?

Comment: ok, but i need proper solution on how to get old environment data into new environment..

Comment: What do you want as a proper solution? SFDC have given you tools to use as well as 3rd parties. You will have to do some work to get the data from org1 to org2.

Comment: It might help to give more details, have you attempted this in a sandbox environment, if so, where are you getting stuck?

Answer (score 1):

Knowledge Article Number: [000005202](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=What-steps-are-needed-to-migrate-my-data-from-one-organization-to-another-1327109132359&language=en_US) goes through the steps to take for moving data.

> In order to import records from one organization into another, you will need to import them in a particular order to maintain their relationships. However,  their relationships are currently defined with their Salesforce IDs (and not their names)  so you will need to match IDs and Names up. You can do this with the VLookup functionality available within Microsoft Excel. For more information on using this functionality, please refer to the following Google search: https://www.google.com/search?q=VLookup+functionality+available+within+Microsoft+Excel&oq=VLookup+functionality+available+within+Microsoft+Excel&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l4.1537j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=0&ie=UTF-8 .
>
> Depending on the records you wish to insert, will depend on the
>   process you will want to follow. If you want to only import Accounts,
>   Contacts, Leads, Solutions or any of your custom object records, you
>   can do so through the traditional import wizards.
>
> In the event that you are needing to insert any of the objects not
>   listed above and you are on the Enterprise or Unlimited editions, you
>   can insert the records through the Data Loader. This can be located
>   at: http://blogs.salesforce.com/features/2006/03/appexchange_dat.html
>
> The Data Loader will permit you to import the records belonging to
>   those objects not on the list above, as well those that are. 
>   Installing Data Loader
>
> When importing the records through the import wizard, make sure that
>   you use the VLookup functionality to map the name of the Account from
>   the Account Record into the Contact records based on the displayed
>   Account ID. When performing the import, you will be able to perform
>   the imports in any order you desire, though the Accounts and Contacts
>   will need to be imported jointly.
>
> When doing so through the Data Loader, you will need to import the
>   Account records prior to performing the VLookup function, as you will
>   perform the matching to the particular Account record based on it's
>   NEW Account ID versus it's old ID or Name. The order in which you will
>   want to import these records is as follows:
>
> Accounts Campaigns Contacts Opportunities Cases Solutions Pricebooks
>   Products Leads Contracts
>
> This will ensure that each of the records will be properly associated
>   as you will be able to define the ID of the related records upon
>   import. If you do not feel confident in your ability to perform these
>   steps yourself, this process can be done by our Professional Services
>   group for a fee. If you are interested in this option, please contact
>   your Account Executive.
>
> In order to migrate from one customized instance of Salesforce to
>   another customized instance of Salesforce, please review the
>   following:
>
> Note: prior to the migration it is important to prepare the Target
>   Instance for the new data.
>
> 1. Mapping between the 2 instances requires all fields from exported org are established in the new target instance. (The customer can
>      generate a schema configuration export by using ANT or Eclipse with
>      the Force.com plug-in. Additionally there are some AppExchange
>      packages that can generate that as well.)
> 2. Other customization of the Target instance, Record Types, Page Layouts, etc.
> 3. Developing Sharing Model to accommodate new user groups if necessary: Profiles, Roles and Sharing Rules
> 4. Reviewing Ownership Rules
> 5. Ensuring all required data points are captured
> 6. Testing migration prior to mass uploads
> 7. Completing Data Validation once migration is complete